Is it possible to show that this equation has purely imaginary roots?
Consider the following equation:
$$\frac{a}{2x}\ln \left(\frac{b +x}{b - x} \right) - 1=0$$
in which $a$ and $b$ are real constants. I know this equation has two real roots, $x_0$ and $-x_0$, if $a < b$. However, if $a > b$, the roots are complex.
My question is: is it possible to demonstrate that these roots, for $a > b$, are (or are not) purely imaginary?

Yes! Just edited the question and included this information.

(See fig. below). As
$$\tanh^{-1}(X)=\tfrac12 \ln\left(\frac{1+X}{1-X}\right),$$
setting $X=x/b$, the initial equation is equivalent (see Remark at the bottom) to
$$\tanh^{-1}(x/b)=x/(2a),\tag{1}$$
itself equivalent (by bijectivity) to
$\underbrace{x/b}_{g(x)}=\underbrace{\tanh(x/(2a))}_{f(x)}\tag{2}$
The two functions $f$ and $g$ defined in (1) are odd ; therefore, it suffices to consider $x \in (0,+\infty)$. On this domain, $f$ being concave with $f(0)=0$, its curve is under its tangent at the origin whose equation $y=x/(2a)$ because $\tanh'(0)=1-\tanh(0)^2=1$.
It remains to compare the resp. slopes of $y=x/(2a)$ and $y=x/b$ to conclude that there are 2 real roots iff $2a<b$ (not $a<b$ !).

Remark : Root $x=0$ that we can see on the graphical representation is a spurious root that we haven't to consider ; indeed, the domain of definition of the initial equation excludes it (it has clearly been introduced when, instead of having $x$ in the denominator, it has been "moved to" the numerator).

Edit : In order to answer your "real" question (intended pun) about the fact that in the case of complex roots (case $2a>b$ as seen above) these complex roots are pure imaginary (real part = $0$), let us come back to equation (1) in wich we replace $x$ by $ix$. (1) will become :
$$\tfrac{ix}{b} = \tanh \left(\tfrac{ix}{2a}\right)=i \tan\left(\tfrac{x}{2a}\right)$$
(the second equality can be verified at once on the Taylor expansions).
Otherwise said,
$$\tfrac{x}{b} = \tan\left(\tfrac{x}{2a}\right)$$
which has an infinite number of roots.

Thank you, but my question was if it is possible to demonstrate that the roots are purely imaginary. Let's say, if complex roots can be written as $x_1 = a_1 + ib_1$ and $x_2 = a_2 + ib_2$, is it possible to demonstrate that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are always equal to $0$?

I understand. Saying that there are real roots iff $2a \le b$ means a contrario that the roots are complex (i.e., with non-zero imaginary parts) iff $2a > b$ but not necessarily with zero real part...

I understand now : there are pure imaginary roots $x=ia$ because : $\arctan a=\frac{i}2\ln(\frac{(1-ia)}{(1+ia)})$
